# Device Orientation on Loading

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, landscape

I am working and I have observed that there is no available landscape App Icons/Launch Images for those targeting iPhone devices so I was wondering **if there is a way to set the orientation of the "Built-In" loading screen for iOS iPhone**? Currently, it is just displayed in Portrait even if I switch to Landscape, it doesn't change orientation.

I saw something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

but this is *forcibly* setting the orientation to...

What I need is to dynamically load the appropriate orientation (by me or by the app).

Please take note that the application haven't load any custom controllers yet (I suppose).

Any Hand?

TIA

Comment: Which Ios virsion R u working on it..?

Comment: MAC OS 10.7.5 (11G63), Xcode 4.4.1 (4F1003), Targeted Device: iPhone, Deployment Target: 4.3

Answer (score 1):

There is no method like this, but you can add an `UIDevice` category in your application delegate, before the `implementation` block as:-

```
@interface UIDevice (MyAwesomeMethodsThatAppleWillNeverAllowMeToUse)
-(void)setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation animated:(BOOL)animated;
-(void)setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
@end
```

Comment: I am receiving an error **Duplicate interface definition for class 'UIDevice' **

Comment: Ok, now I get it, its a category... so is this called automatically?